# writing "print" statements in Blender console

Tags: python, command-line

I know and use the great script from Codemanx from which you can start python script in the Blender-console and you would see print statements in the Blender-console. Unfortunately it looks like this only works for "direct" running the python code.

I have something like this:

```
def my_handler(scene):
    
    print("Frame Change", scene.frame_current)
    
    

    print ("whatever")
    
    


bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

so here i call a function (myHandler) via frame handler. Can i get those print statements somehow in the Blender-console?

Blender console:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. By Blender-console do you mean a Linux terminal or the command line (cmd.exe)? So you're saying the print statement is not outputed? Can you also share the command you are running in the Blender-console?

Comment: No, I mean the console in Blender. It is all outputted correctly in terminal. But I would love to see it in the Blender console.

Comment: hmmm not sure if you mean the System console or the Python console. but I can see print outputs in both. or just show me a pic of the blender console.

Comment: try my code, run it, and you will see....nothing in the blender console ;)

Comment: i see something. u have to scroll the timeline to trigger the event to print XD

Comment: i know - and as i said - i can see my print statements in my terminal - but not in the blender console....maybe it is working on windows. But on mac....unfortunately not.

Comment: ah u confused me with "blender console". its the [Python Console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html)

Comment: ok, sorry for my wrong "naming" ...but i changed the question just for u  with a pic...so you could have known ;)

Comment: hahaha no worries sorry for my confusion  hey but i will try to figure it out tomorrow!

Comment: Do you know codemanx script? Which I mentioned?

Comment: i see it in github. havn't tried it but im a unix/linux nerd so i should figure it out :D